# Get all property of Group using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model, web-services, csom, groups

Unable to get all property of SharePoint group using CSOM.

```
GroupCollection collGroup = clientx.Web.SiteGroups;
clientx.Load(collGroup, grups => grups.Include(grup => grup.Title, grup => grup.Description, grup => grup.Owner, grup => grup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership, grup => grup.AllowMembersEditMembership, grup => grup.AutoAcceptRequestToJoinLeave, grup => grup.AllowRequestToJoinLeave, grup => grup.OwnerTitle, grup => grup.RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting, grup => grup.Id, grup => grup.LoginName));

clientx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Is there any way to fetch all possible property of site group?

I want to do it by `Managed code(CSOM)`, not by Server side or JSOM or REST.

`WebService` is also preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your code and got an unknown error. So i tried removing each field in the LINQ query and I found the error is due to `grup => grup.Owner`. I have changed it to `grup => grup.OwnerTitle` and the code worked fine. Also for getting each property value of a group loop the group collection object and get its value as per below code.

```
GroupCollection collGroup = oClientContext.Web.SiteGroups;
oClientContext.Load(collGroup, grups => grups.Include(grup => grup.Title, grup => grup.Description, grup => grup.OwnerTitle, grup => grup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership, grup => grup.AllowMembersEditMembership, grup => grup.AutoAcceptRequestToJoinLeave, grup => grup.AllowRequestToJoinLeave, grup => grup.OwnerTitle, grup => grup.RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting, grup => grup.Id, grup => grup.LoginName));
oClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Group oGroup in collGroup)
{
    oClientContext.Load(oGroup);
    oClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Welcome. If the answer helped you, mark it as answer.

Comment: Hi nagarajan, today I tried with `grup => grup.Owner` and its working. I think problem is something else.

Comment: Thats great. Mark it as answer then.

Comment: Is there any way to get `owner` also?

Answer (score 2):

grup.Owner returns Principal object. so you can't load it using LINQ. You can load owner object for group inside foreach loop like this.

```
   `   GroupCollection collGroup = context.Web.SiteGroups;
       context.Load(collGroup);
             context.Load(collGroup, grups => grups.Include(grup => grup.Title, grup => grup.Description, grup => grup.OwnerTitle, grup => grup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership, grup => grup.AllowMembersEditMembership, grup => grup.AutoAcceptRequestToJoinLeave, grup => grup.AllowRequestToJoinLeave, grup => grup.OwnerTitle, grup => grup.RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting, grup => grup.Id, grup => grup.LoginName));
             context.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach(Group g in collGroup)
            {
                Principal temp = g.Owner;
                context.Load(temp, t => t.LoginName, t => t.PrincipalType, t => t.Id);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(temp.Id);
                Console.WriteLine(temp.LoginName);
                Console.WriteLine(temp.PrincipalType);
            }`
```

or You can specifically load properties of owner in the GroupCollection LINQ itself like this:

`context.Load(collGroup, grups => grups.Include(grup => grup.Title, grup => grup.Owner.PrincipalType, grup => grup.Owner.LoginName, grup => grup.Owner.Id);`

Hope this helps.